# SUM of Union ALL? is it possible?

Tags: sql, sum, sql-server-2016, union-all

How I can SUM 2 Union all's for a field?
Basically, I got 1 table working with 2 rows on it. Now I want 
to add 
3rd row wherein I want to SUM a field in the first row and 
SUM a field 
of
2nd row and have the two SUM results appear in the third row, 
just as 
a query (not create a new table). I tried UNION but this gives 
an 
error.

```
Date Type                     Orders         TOTAL
13/03 Sales Order             300            15000
13/03 Invoice                 200            10000
```

-------------I want to add third row to get the total of 1500 and 1000------

```
(How can I get this value of 25000) as a field?
```

yes, I have applied union all to get these the 2 rows above. But how about if I want to add the third row? does it mean I have to put another UNION ALL?

Comment: Which database are you using?  The answer to your question would depend on that.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: yes, I have applied union all to get these the 2 rows above. But how about if I want to add the third row? does it mean I have to put another UNION ALL?

Comment: @TrishFernandez You've asked this question multiple times without even telling us which database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Try to wrap a select to the dataset and sum the field you wanted.

```
SELECT SUM(value) as total from(
SELECT 'A2' as field2,'A3' as field3,'A' as name,100 as value 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'B2' as field2,'B3' as field3,'B' as name,200 as value)
as tbl
```

UNION ALL the total row ... certainly it is much faster if you can use temp table to store the first result (you can expect it is very slow if you execute it)

```
SELECT 'A2' as field2,'A3' as field3,'A' as name,100 as value 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'B2' as field2,'B3' as field3,'B' as name,200 as value
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C1' as field2,'C2' as field3, 'C' as name, SUM(value) as total from (
SELECT 'A2' as field2,'A3' as field3,'A' as name,100 as value 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'B2' as field2,'B3' as field3,'B' as name,200 as value)
as tbl
```

IF your query is written in the stored procedure, then you can apply temptable as below

```
;WITH tmpTable
AS (
SELECT 'A2' as field2,'A3' as field3,'A' as name,100 as value 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'B2' as field2,'B3' as field3,'B' as name,200 as value
)
SELECT * FROM tmpTable UNION ALL
SELECT 'C1' as field2,'C2' as field3, 'C' as name, SUM(value) as total from tmpTable
```

Comment: yes, I have applied union all to get these the 2 rows above. But how about if I want to add the third row? does it mean I have to put another UNION ALL?

Comment: yes lol, i think there is smarter method, but it works actually

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you want to do:

```
select Date, Type, Orders, TOTAL
from
(
    select Date, Type, Orders, TOTAL, 1 AS pos
    from t
    union all
    select NULL, NULL, NULL, sum(total), 2
    from t
) t
order by pos;
```

Comment: yes, I have applied union all to get these the 2 rows above. But how about if I want to add third row? does it mean I have to put another UNION ALL?